# jq not working with exclamation mark as an input

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh, jq

I am passing username and password to jq the following way:

```
json=$(jq -n --arg u "user_dev" --arg p "user!" '{username: $u, password: $p}')
```

However, it is failing and giving the following output:

```
-bash: !": event not found
```

It seem that it is not liking exclamation mark with the `arg p "user!"`

Comment: Efforts to build a [mcve] presumably would have lead to a discovery that this is reproducible without `jq` involved at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shell is interpreting it as a history expansion. Use single quotes instead to prevent that.

```
json=$(jq -n --arg u "user_dev" --arg p 'user!' '{username: $u, password: $p}')
```

That said, `bash` 4.3 includes a fix to prevent that from happening. From the changelog:

> l.  The history expansion character (!) does not cause history expansion when
>       followed by the closing quote in a double-quoted string.